# JavaScript undefinded variable after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since I loaded a project to the web server I am getting this error message after the first refresh:

> TypeError: oModel.responseJSON is undefined

Although the variable exists and AJAX succeed. The error refers to this line:

```
<body onload="displayEntries(oModel.responseJSON.results);">
```

I load before the body close tag the following JS:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/user.js"></script>
```

JS runs in strict mode and in the "user.js" I have this code:

```
    let oModel = $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    }); 
function displayEntries(entries) {
    $("#div").empty();
    let html = "";

    jQuery.each(entries, function(i, entry) {
        html = '<div id="cid-' + i + '" class="entry">' + entry.name + '</div>';
        $("#div").append(txt);
    });
}
```

When I enter "oModel.responseJSON.results" into the console, it is displayed correctly.

Comment: You don't have a "success" callback set up for your AJAX operation and are trying to access it before it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're trying to access value of a variable before the AJAX call is over.

Call the `displayEntries()` function after the AJAX call is over like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.php',
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
  displayEntries(data)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous

Get rid of `onload="displayEntries` and just call the function in succcess callback of `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    dataType: 'json'
}).then(displayEntries);
```